# Javascript. is this an Object literal or constructor syntax or something else...?

Tags: javascript

Lastly ... the first line ...  var phonebookEntry = {} is this an Object literal or constructor syntax ... I don't think it's an literal, but then if it's constructor --- isn't this the right syntax for object constructor ===> var myObj = new Object(); <=== I'm confused ... or else there's a third syntax/way for creating objects...

```
var phonebookEntry = {};

phonebookEntry.name = 'Oxnard Montalvo';
phonebookEntry.number = '(555) 555-5555';
phonebookEntry.phone = function() {            
funtion works, it has no any parameter...
  console.log('Calling ' + this.name + ' at ' + this.number + '...');
};

phonebookEntry.phone();
```

Comment: Please explain your question "How's that?" is not specific enough

Comment: Functions dont *need* a parameter.

Comment: @tymeJV I'm thinking he's asking how it is outputting the `name` and `number` without there being parameters for it. The `this` keyword is referring to the functions parent.

Comment: @tymeJV In line 5... a function without any parameter? How's that working?

Comment: is it really the fact that the function doesn't have any parameters or any name that bugs you?

Answer (score 5):

This line:

```
phonebookEntry.phone = function() {
  console.log('Calling ' + this.name + ' at ' + this.number + '...');
};
```

creates a `Function` object and assigns it to the `phone` attribute of `phonebookEntry`. The function is not called at that point. Later (the next line, actually):

```
phonebookEntry.phone();
```

calls the function, passing no arguments and binding `this` to `phonebookEntry` within the body of the function. Thus, during that call, `this.name` is an alias for `phonebookEntry.name` and similarly for the `number` property.

Answer (score 0):

name and number are properties of phonebookEntry. They don't need to be passed as arguments.

Answer (score 0):

This creates the function within an object:

```
phonebookEntry.phone = function() {    
  console.log('Calling ' + this.name + ' at ' + this.number + '...');
};
```

This calls the function:

```
phonebookEntry.phone();
```

It is able to utilize `this` to describe the parent object(phonebookEntry) and is then able to grab other information such as name, number, or any other information stored within that object.